# ListBox.ObjectCollection definition issue for 'Item"

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

To preface, I'm still learning C#.

I am making a form that combines 2 text files to make 1 list and I have hitch with the following:

```
sWriter.WriteLine(listBox3.Items.Item(i));

listBox3.Items.Add(listBox1.Items.Item(i) + ":" + listBox2.Items.Item(o));

label2.Text = listBox3.Items.Count;
```

**Full Code:**
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qKfvn5jQfC/

Comment: What is the intended output? What is happening or not happening instead? Why do you ahve WriteLine and a ListBox in teh same piece of code, as usually console and GUI technologies are at odds with one another.

Comment: when you choose the text file it puts whats in the text file in the listboxes (2 for each of the text files) 3rd listbox is for the combined result. The 3 lines I have in my post seem to be where vs complains about 'Item"

Comment: I think you messed up the array indexers. `listBox1.Items[i].Item` is closer to what it should be in C#. But as I do not know wich of the 6+ ListBoxes we even talk about, it is hard to say anything with certainty.

Comment: Full code in the paste...

Comment: This appears to have fixed one issue 

listBox1.Items.IndexOf(i)

Comment: Please specify **wich** listbox you are working with. Because having the index handed in as a function argument is *not how .NET does Indexers*. Indexers have a very specific approach with dedicated syntax. And if that really is that listboxes syntax, the programmer of said listbox propably messed up royaly. And one messup of this magnitude indicates other issues with the code for those listboxes.